# Endless recycler view scoll listener called when there are not enough items on screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I implemented [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) to get infinite scrolling working with my recycler view.
I set it up like this:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(glm) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            anotherOne(page, mScope, mCurrentSortPreference, false);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onloadmore called");
        }
    });
```

The method `anotherOne()` loads data in the recycler view from an API with an async task.
If I have 20+ items to fetch from the API (in the initial call) it works fine. This is because my grid allows displaying maximum of 20 results on the screen at the same time.

But if the api returns few items (like 2 or 3) instead of only those being displayed, the `onLoadMore()` gets called repeatedly, until it fills the screen with the same 2 or 3 items. Then it stops.

[Schreenshot](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/22935424/19666774/84d0ca28-9a44-11e6-841a-915a2e2b3c03.png)

This is the only line I modified in the EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener.java:

```
private int visibleThreshold = 1;
```

Thank you.

E: added code

```
private void anotherOne(int currPage, int scope, String sort, boolean o){ 
    String override = Boolean.valueOf(o).toString();
    (new FetchMoviesTask()).execute(Integer.valueOf(currPage).toString(),
            Integer.valueOf(scope).toString(), sort, override, "");
}
```

Comment: Do you check if you are not downloading data already? I mean perhaps there are few requests going for the same set of data and hence the duplicates

Comment: From the logcat I see that this log is being spammed `Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onloadmore called");`

Comment: add some flag, that will block further load until the previous one finished

Comment: I think you need add some code to check that the `items.size() < size_data_on_api` then call `anotherOne()` so if the items.size() already same that will not call repeatedly

Comment: There must be an easier way, this involves lots of coding

Answer (score 1):

From the source documentation:

> // The minimum number of items to have below your current scroll position
>
> // before loading more.
>
> private int visibleThreshold = 5;

This means that it must have at least `visibleThreshold` more itens not being shown, in order to be safe-ish and not gather more data... so you are requesting:

```
private int visibleThreshold = 1;
```

This means that your data set must have "full screen plus visibleThreshold", since you have no more data, it assumes you do, requests the wrong offset, and gets the last one repeatedly, until you have "full screen plus visibleThreshold" data units.

Lower your `Treshold`, or return `false` on `onLoadMore`

#### Edit:

From documentation again, please try the following:

```
@Override
      public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
          // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
          // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to your AdapterView
          loadNextDataFromApi(totalItemsCount); 
          return true; // ONLY if more data is actually being loaded; false otherwise.
      }

public void loadNextDataFromApi(int offset) {
  // Send an API request to retrieve appropriate paginated data 
  //  --> Send the request including an offset value (i.e `page`) as a query parameter.
  //  --> Deserialize and construct new model objects from the API response
  //  --> Append the new data objects to the existing set of items inside the array of items
  //  --> Notify the adapter of the new items made with `notifyDataSetChanged()`
}
```

Comment: If I set `visibleThreshold` to 0 it doesn't load anything even when it should.

Comment: Edit your question, detail the `anotherOne` method. Read the answer again. If your `Treshold` is 0, then you have 0 more itens "out of screen", in your `onLoadMore`, you should check the total or if the data set received is not "complete", "empty", or even "failed".

Comment: I edited the answer. I don't understand very good. What should I check for in onLoadMore? it gives me the total item and the current page, but I don't even know what totalItems is.

Answer (score 1):

In my Case i forget to add line.Hope it help somebody.
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);

Answer (score 0):

If you set a breakpoint in the onScrolled() method in EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener you will know why. If there aren't enough items on the screen, the recyclerView will automatically scroll and the onScrolled method would be called. Since there aren't enough items to occupy the screen, the lastVisibleItemPosition + threshold will always be larger than the totalNumberOfItems. As a result of which, the onLoadMore method will be repeatedly called.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, with not enough items instantiated with the recyclerView, can you actually see the new items being added to the recyclerView if you dont manually scroll the screen?